# Issue with query, won't accept condition

Tags: sql

I have this question.
There is this query i use:

```
"SELECT  formas.*,
        SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET,
        SMS_SERVISI.MBYLLUR,
        SMS_SERVISI.time_added,
        servis_furnitor.id_servis,
        servis_furnitor.furnitori,
        servis_furnitor.kohezgjatja,
               referenca.id_referenca,
        referenca.shenime

FROM formas
LEFT JOIN servis_furnitor
        ON formas.furnitori = servis_furnitor.id_servis
LEFT JOIN SMS_SERVISI
        ON formas.ID = SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET
        AND formas.sektori_pergjegjes ='A'
        LEFT JOIN referenca
        ON formas.ID = referenca.id_referenca  "
```

My problem is i don't get the part of the condition `AND formas.sektori_pergjegjes ='A'`
isn't executed. Maybe i've done a misplacement, or something else, but i can't get it to work.

Please take a look at this.
Thanks

Comment: can you give more information? like adding sample data with desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
"SELECT  formas.*,
    SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET,
    SMS_SERVISI.MBYLLUR,
    SMS_SERVISI.time_added,
    servis_furnitor.id_servis,
    servis_furnitor.furnitori,
    servis_furnitor.kohezgjatja,
           referenca.id_referenca,
    referenca.shenime

FROM formas
LEFT JOIN servis_furnitor
    ON formas.furnitori = servis_furnitor.id_servis
LEFT JOIN SMS_SERVISI
    ON formas.ID = SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET
LEFT JOIN referenca
    ON formas.ID = referenca.id_referenca  
WHERE formas.sektori_pergjegjes ='A'"
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition `AND formas.sektori_pergjegjes ='A'` is only executed for the join results since it is part of the join conditions. If you want all the data to comply with your filter you need to move it into the where clause.

```
SELECT  formas.*,
        SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET,
        SMS_SERVISI.MBYLLUR,
        SMS_SERVISI.time_added,
        servis_furnitor.id_servis,
        servis_furnitor.furnitori,
        servis_furnitor.kohezgjatja,
        referenca.id_referenca,
        referenca.shenime    
FROM formas
LEFT JOIN servis_furnitor
        ON formas.furnitori = servis_furnitor.id_servis
LEFT JOIN SMS_SERVISI
        ON formas.ID = SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET
LEFT JOIN referenca
        ON formas.ID = referenca.id_referenca
WHERE formas.sektori_pergjegjes ='A'
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the and condition as where and see if its solves

```
"SELECT  formas.*,
        SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET,
        SMS_SERVISI.MBYLLUR,
        SMS_SERVISI.time_added,
        servis_furnitor.id_servis,
        servis_furnitor.furnitori,
        servis_furnitor.kohezgjatja,
               referenca.id_referenca,
        referenca.shenime

FROM formas
LEFT JOIN servis_furnitor
        ON formas.furnitori = servis_furnitor.id_servis
LEFT JOIN SMS_SERVISI
        ON formas.ID = SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET

        LEFT JOIN referenca
        ON formas.ID = referenca.id_referenca 
 WHERE formas.sektori_pergjegjes ='A' "
```